# Eclipse Photon - SVN / Maven not handled as Java-Project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I moved forward to Eclipse 4.8. My Projects Maven projects under subversion is not displayed as Java Project and the `pom.xml` is displayed in XML-Editor instead of the well-meant pom-editor.

Steps I done:

- Installed eclipse photon
- Opend new/empty workspace
- Installed subversive from update-site.
- Restart
- Installed svn-connector SVNKIT from subversive-plugin.
- Restart
- Checkout project from SVN.
- Remove project without delete on HDD.
- Import existing maven project from workspace.
- Hit "Maven->Update Project..." on all projects in the workspace.

The Project's icon is showing the M-Icon-Overlay let me think it is a maven project. The Project's icon does not contain the J-Icon-Overlay what let me think he does not treat it as a Java project.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to delete the file without deleting its content, delete the `.project` file and reopen it via _File > Open Projects from File System..._.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesnt work at the moment. I created a workspace in an older version and opend the workspace again in the new eclipse photon. It asks to convert it to the new eclipse's workspace and everything is fine.